# Photoshop action to combine multiple photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I'm trying to recreate this:

[image: image grid]

I know it could be easily done manually, but I'm wondering if anyone has come across a tutorial or knows how to create this automatically with `actions` in Photoshop?

I want to be able to select a number of photos and be able to create something similar automatically. If anyone knows anyway to accomplish this efficiently with any software I'd really like to know.

Comment: You're referring to what's known as the "packing problem." If you were to do this in Photoshop, you would need to use the scripting api.

Comment: As someone who writes Photoshop scripts a lot, I can tell you this would be very complex. That said, it would be an interesting challenge for me and I may have a solution (no promises, though)

Comment: Will the number of images always be the same? This could be done with nested actions.

Comment: I'd probably use indesign and import that to photoshop. [About indesign gap tool and gridify](http://creativepro.com/exactly-indesign-tool/). [Little more about gridify](https://www.adobe.com/support/indesign/gettingstarted/pdfs/indesign_howto_a_grid.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If no Action Script is made available to you. I think it may be more efficient, personally, to use InDesign for any layout work as it offers better tools for layout than photoshop does.

You could easily build a template layout of empty frames (frame tool) that matches the above layout orientation (or any layout). Then bulk place the photos you would like to use into the empty frames. I have used this to make templates for photographers in wedding photography.

This option would not work well˚ unless you are dealing with a set number of photos (like the 8 above).

˚A variable number of photos (think Pinterest site/app...) may work if you use a little gem of mathematics - Pythagorean Tiling (similarly Tessellation).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good photoshop action http://www.filedropper.com/13photocollage I found on the web, this is an easy way but I don't recommend it to you, maybe it will not work for harder things.
also I recommend you this good tutorial [digital-photography-school](http://digital-photography-school.com/make-photoshop-collage-9-steps/)
they teach in 9 easy steps how to make what you want.

also I recommend this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JogH4Mfc2nI) by Tuts + Illustration wich teach you how to create an image collage in indesign

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the tych extension? http://lumens.se/tychpanel/

Comment: Welcome to GD. Your answer may help the OP but please read our Help Center Guidelines and know that new users posting link only answers tend to receive down-voted votes. Do you mind adding a little more information to help the OP so your answer will be better?